# Upload unnattached image from frontend

Tags: images, uploads, attachments, front-end

I am using the below function to let users upload files from the front end. It works great except that I would like the file to NOT be attached to any post. Currently, the file is automatically attaching itself to the page that I'm using for uploads (mysite.com/publish). I would like it to just be unattached instead.

What should I change below to make that work?

Here is the functions:

```
    // Uploads images from the front-end

function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

// check to make sure its a successful upload
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
return $attach_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [`media_handle_upload` in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L204) you'll see how it uses [`wp_handle_upload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) to do just the uploading part of the process without inserting an attachment.